# How can I change the docker storage driver of a Kubernetes POD that is running on EKS Anywhere running containerd

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

Does anyone know how to run docker build from inside of a Kubernetes POD running on EKS Anywhere / Kubernetes 1.28 / Ubuntu 22.04 / Jenkins + Kubernetes Plugin and have the docker storage driver be overlay2?

I am having a very hard time getting docker in a docker to run in anything other than VFS mode. I am trying use a Kubernetes pod spun up from the Kubernetes plugin in Jenkins to run docker build. This works and has been working but the vfs directory is getting too big so I want to change it to overlay2.

I was able to get it to change from vfs > overlay2 by manually removing containerd from the Kubernetes "worker" node / host system and installing docker using apt-get. I was also able to get it to switch to use "fuse-overlayFS in a different test by installing it on the base container that Kubernetes is spinning up as a temp slave. Changing the eks anywhere node / host system to use Docker instead of Containerd seems wrong and looks to be unsupported. Fuse-overlayFS gives all kinds of errors and also seems like a bad option.

From the EKS worker node, if I run "crictl info" I do not see a storage driver, but I do see snapshotter which is using "overlay"